# WCF MSMQ last message in the transaction

Tags: wcf, msmq, msmq-transaction

Is there is a way in WCF MSMQ to know if I am processing the last message in the transaction?

I did lot of searches I found that there is a property `IsLastInTransaction` but this property not available in `MsmqMessage<T>` Class it only available in `System.Messaging.Message`

Anybody know how can I determine if this is the last message in the transaction.